# Saving CSV list to database from a URL with GET Parameters - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to integrate Ekomi's product review feedback into our product detail pages.  They have provided a URL with GET paramaters as follows:

http://api.ekomi.de/get_productfeedback.php

```
interface_id* - Your eKomi interface ID)
interface_pw* - Your eKomi interface password
type* - csv = RFC 4180 - comma-separated values (delimiter=, enclosure=")
product - A single product_id or the keyword "all"
```

This eventually looks like this (our details have been hidden obviously).

```
http://api.ekomi.de/get_productfeedback.php?interface_id=[OURID]&interface_pw=[OURPW]&version=cust-1.0.0&type=csv
```

Which returns a CSV after RFC4180(delimiter=, enclosure=") with the following items:

```
UNIXTIME,customer_id,product_id,rating,feedback
```

Which looks like this...

```
1420215053,498,LWP0004,5,"Excellent service on a quality product"
1420215053,498,LWP0040,5,"Excellent service on a quality product"
1420573617,535,LWP0350,5,"Bought to experiment with, very good kit"
1421229382,552,LWP0173,4,"Good price ,"
1421343151,558,LWP0004,5,"Quality very good"
1421343151,558,LWP0016,5,"Quality very good"
1421412155,560,LWP0004,5,"Replacement of high energy bulbs"
1421574027,562,LWP0038,5,"tell everyone"
1421959977,575,LWP0004,5,"Lighting our revamped kitchen"
1422129969,591,LWP0038,5,"All good thanks, will use again"
1422129969,591,LWP0284,5,"All good thanks"
etc
```

EKomi also supplied the following PHP script...

```
<?php

/*
 * Creates a table to store product reviews on your server
 *
 * You must be connected to your server's DB before running this function
*/
function create_table($tableName){
$sql = "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$tableName` (
`timestamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`order_id` varchar(64) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
`product_id` varchar(64) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
`stars` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`review` text character set latin1 NOT NULL,
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40110 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}

/*
* Access the eKomi API to check for new feedback
*
* You can find your eKomi API inteface ID and interface password in your 
* eKomi customer area on the right hand side.
*/
function check_product_feedback($tableName, $interfaceId, $interfacePass) {
$url = "http://api.ekomi.de/get_productfeedback.php?
 interface_id=$interfaceId&interface_pw=$interfacePass&type=csv&range=1m&charset=utf-8";
if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2048, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` 

(`timestamp`,`order_id`,`product_id`,`stars`,`review`)
VALUES
('" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]) . "',
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]) . "',
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]) . "',
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]) . "',
'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]) . "')";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
fclose($handle);
return true;
}
return false;
}

/*
* Look in the feedback table for reviews for a specific product ID
* 
* Return results as an array.
*/
function get_feedback_for_product($tableName, $productId){
$sql="SELECT * FROM `$tableName` WHERE `product_id` like '$productId'";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($re = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$reviews[] = $re;
}
return isset($reviews)?$reviews:array();
}

/*
* Get the average feedback score for a given product ID
*
* Return average as a float
*/
function get_average($tableName, $productId){
$avgArr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT AVG( `stars` ) AS `avg`
FROM `$tableName`
WHERE `product_id` = '$productId'"));
return $avgArr['avg'];
}

?>
```

I have our MySQL database connection details I'm just completely unfamiliar with how you would even begin to capture the CSV list into database by calling the URL with the GET Paramaters?

Wouldn't that need to be triggered somehow?

I'd really appreciate it if someone could take me by the hand on this one as EKomi don't offer any support on this apart from the above.

Thank you so much.
NJ

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you need to collect the csv from another server. therefore, if your hosting provider supports fopen on urls, you can directly use

```
$url = "http://api.ekomi.de/get_productfeedback.php?interface_id=[OURID]&interface_pw=[OURPW]&version=cust-1.0.0&type=csv"

if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2048, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        /*process your data here*/
        $timestamp = $data[0]; //timestamp
        $orderId = $data[1];
        $productId = $data[2];
        $stars = $data[3];
        $review = $data[4];
    }
}
```

if your host doesn't support fopen on external urls, you should fetch your csv first using cURL or similar,

```
//generate a unique temporary filename
$tmpFile = tempnam ("/tmp", "yourPrefix");

//initialize a filehandle
$fp = fopen($tmpFile, 'w');

//initialize a curl session
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, //is used to return the transfer after execution
    CURLOPT_FILE => $fp,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url  //pass the $url from above with the GET values
));

// Send the request
curl_exec($curl);

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

// Close file handle
fclose($fp);

/*process your data as before but use fopen($tmpFile... instead of fopen($url...*/
```

UPDATE:

for your sql statements, I suggest that you use the `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions, since `mysql` is deprecated.

to speed up a big insert of values, use something like this for your query:

```
//before your while loop    
$query = array();

 //in your loop where you process your data
 $query[] = "('".$data[0]."', '".$data[1]."', '".$data[2]."', '".$data[3]."', '".$data[4]."')";
```

and after your loop

```
$tableName = "yourTable";
$sql = "INSERT INTO
             `$tableName`
            ( `$tableName`.`timestamp`,
             `$tableName`.`orderId`,
             `$tableName`.`productId`,
             `$tableName`.`stars`,
             `$tableName`.`review`)
            VALUES
";

$sql .= implode(",", $query);
```

and send your sql statement `$sql` to the server

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this though? Is this code that should sit above the HEAD tag on our product detail page?  The product detail page displays products based on a querystring, which I understand we'd use to pick out the relevant review from the data that's returned from Ekomi.

Comment: Basically you won't import the whole csv every time someone hits your page. Normally you would collect the data by a scheduled job. I.e. a cronjob is a common place for such tasks. After all the collected data is in your database, you can simply link your query to the other table with the reviews.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the csv first, basicaly using explode() function to have an array of the product reviews, then you can easily insert these data in your database, using a foreach on your array for example.

Comment: I can only have an array of the product reviews if it has first saved those reviews to database.  I've installed the above script on my page but it's not creating the MySQL table and it's not inserting any data into it.

Comment: Just use create_table() for create the structure of the table. After, you have to create the function that insert data into it. You'll need to write an SQL request (INSERT) and run it with PHP.

Comment: We're already using create_table() in the PHP script that EKomi provides "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$tableName`...".  It also has an SQL request (INSERT), which is why I'm confused about why it's not working.  When I check our MySQL database no table has been written to it.

Comment: somewhere you have to call the functions, which are provided by EKomi. but i suggest that you write your own importer, since the provided one uses `mysql` functions, this extensions is highly deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: @NathanJones if you are not used to user defined functions in PHP, have a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: The problem is that this is over my head and Ekomi won't help. I understand that I should be moving to mysqli so it's disappointing that Ekomi have sent us a deprecated script. I don't suppose you'd be interested in some freelance work would you?

Comment: @NathonJones I'm interessing, you can send me an email at tom@tomtomtom.fr